# Create PDF file with contents from the database

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I would want to print tickets in pdf. I was already able to retrieve the ticket details like customer name, order id, order items, and total bill. I would want to put this details in the .pdf file ready for printing. I'm using html and php tags in retrieving these ticket details from the database. How can I convert to .pdf all items echoed in .php file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/).

Comment: I used dompdf but I can't display contents that are from the DB. Dompdf only uses html tags for pdf contents right? It won't work if i use <?php echo ...?> ?

Comment: DOMPDF will take a HTML document and transform it to PDF. If you generate a full HTML document representing your ticket and pass that to DOMPDF then it can render your PDF as desired.

Comment: Set DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP to true in dompdf_config.inc.php, this will enable php inline php script, but you have to use `<script>` tag rather than the short tag.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) to create PDFs from PHP. It's still actively being developed and has a lot of features you don't find in other libs (yet). Just look at their examples page to see how easy it is to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> http://pear.php.net/package/File_PDF

Answer (score 0):

You can find exactly what you need..
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script10.php
Also many useful exaplmes are given here. [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)