# Print table in pdf using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

I want to print mysql database value in tabular format in PDF using php and I want to include header and footer as well on every page of PDF. The problem I face is every last row of the table in PDF is breaks and displays into two parts and the footer is display on another page. So is there any way to stop breaking of a table row which is just above the footer division and print it on another page???

My another question is if I want to give more than one page size in pdf then how can I do it???

Comment: You should provide some code of what you tried for us to be able to help you

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of the below php scripts to generate dynamic PDF documents

1. [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)
2. [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
3. [MPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)
4. [DOMPDF](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/)

I have answered it by searching multiple previous stackoverflow answers. You can see them here [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500576/create-pdf-file-with-contents-from-the-database), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349873/how-to-generate-pdf-file-from-dynamic-data-coming-from-mysql-database-in-php),..

Answer (score 1):

You can use tcpdf http://www.tcpdf.org/ for this check the examples here http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php . All the features required by you are available in this library